# Why do we need NoOp types?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, option-type, api-design

*Note: This is not a Swift-only question, it's related in every language with `Optional` type.*

I see some Swift projects doing that: `var foo: Foo = NoOpFoo()`
AFAIK this basically means "this foo does nothing" and can be also expressed as `var foo: Foo? = nil`

**I'm wondering what can be the reason(s) behind `NoOp`-instead-of-`Optional` decision?**

1. I can think of performance first: `Optional` seems to add a few more lines to assembly output (but I'm not really convinced with that).
2. The reason could be boilerplate of unwrapping optionals as well: but most of the examples I've seen are types that don't even return values, therefore call sites don't need to unwrap neither.
3. There could be historical reasons too, for example in Java it's tricky to deal with `NullPointerException` so `NoOp`s may come handy... but in Swift?

[Here is an example from swift-log project](https://github.com/apple/swift-log/blob/main/Sources/Logging/Logging.swift#L735):

```swift
public struct Logger {
    var handler: LogHandler
    internal init(_ handler: LogHandler) {
        self.handler = handler
    }
}
public struct SwiftLogNoOpLogHandler: LogHandler { ... }
```

`Logger` is designed to work with a `LogHandler`; to my understanding if you pass `NoOpHandler` to your `Logger` then you should probably turn your `yourLogger: Logger` into `myLogger: Logger? = nil`

Real-world use cases and/or your personal experiences would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is the "Null object pattern", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Comment: by the definition "_...an object which implements the expected interface, but whose method body is empty..._", `Logger?` is following null object pattern too: it has the same interface and its implementation does nothing. Plus, it's a built-in language feature, it doesn't require extra code on our side.

i'm wondering whether there are cases where `NoOp` way is preferred over `Optional` way as both implement the same null object pattern?